# splitting inequalty symbols in string to tokens? (Java/Regex)

Tags: java, regex, equation

I'm trying to split an arithmetic equation string into tokens in Java. These equations also include inequality symbols !=, <=, >=, >, and <.

eg. (2*2<=5) should be split as:

( ,
2 ,
* ,
2 ,
<= ,
5 ,
)

Right now, my solution adds a space before & after each operator then splitting it by white spaces but I'm having trouble differentiating <= and < when I do so.  I reckon, you'd need a regex that checks if there's no = after the < or not, but I can't seem to get it come up with one that works.

How would I go about doing this? Or is there a better way?

What I do right now:

```
String[] tokens = expression
            .replaceAll("\\+", " + ")
            .replaceAll("\\^", " ^ ")
            .replaceAll("^-", "-1*") 
            .replaceAll("-\\(", "-1*(")
            .replaceAll("-", " -")
            .replaceAll("\\*", " * ")
            .replaceAll("/", " / ")
            .replaceAll("!", " !")
            .replaceAll(">", " >")
            .replaceAll("<", " <")
            .replaceAll("\\(", "( ")
            .replaceAll("\\)", " )")
            .split(" ");
```

Comment: **I reckon, you'd need a regex that checks if there's no = after the < or not.** You _could_ do that. You could also just check for `<=` before `<` and it would resolve itself. Depending on performance requirements, this is also going to be a very slow solution. `StringUtils.replaceEach` from Apache StringUtils might be faster.

Comment: Use should use regex to look for \d(<=)\d and then replace the captured group with " <= ". The other should be \d(<)\d.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with a StringTokenizer. The Output

> [(, 2.0, *, 2.0, <, =, 5.0, )]

was produced by the following code:

```
    StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader("(2*2<=5)"));
    List<String> expression = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            switch(tokenizer.ttype) {
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                    expression.add(String.valueOf(tokenizer.nval));
                    break;
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
                    expression.add(tokenizer.sval);
                    break;
                default:  // operator
                    expression.add(String.valueOf((char) tokenizer.ttype));
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString(expression.toArray()));
```

If you need more information, have a look at the Java-API
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html

Answer (score 1):

Check if following solution helps you.

Here I assume that the input is an **arithmetic equation** (not any other string) and contains only **whole numbers** i.e., 2, not decimals i.e., 2.0.

```
private static void method(String str){
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("[^\\d]+");
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("[\\d]+");
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(str);
    Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(str);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(matcher1.find()){
        list.add(matcher1.group(0));
        if(matcher2.find()){
            list.add(matcher2.group(0));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Token list is::");
    for(String st:list){
        System.out.print(st+",");
    }
}
```

If I pass **(2*2<=5)** to the above method, it will output the following.

> Token list is::
>
> (,2,*,2,<=,5,),

Comment: Thanks! Can I get an explanation on what's going on in the code? From what I understand, the first pattern collects all the numbers while the second patter collects everything else, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, **pattern1** is for all non-numeric characters while **pattern2** is for all numeric characters. Using a loop, the passed string is checked against these patterns and when a match is found, it is stored in the list. So at the end of the loop, list contains all the tokens of your equation.

Comment: @Dylan, If you are satisfied with my explanation, please accept this answer by clicking tick mark on the top left corner of it.